# Pokemon go isnt letting me hatch my eggs

Tags: pokemon-go

My 2km egg is stuck at 1.37km and when I walk it stays at 1.37km. I have already tried restarting the game but it still doesn't update. How can I fix this?

Comment: How far have you walked? Sometimes it takes awhile to update.

Comment: not sure if coincidence but mine is stuck at 2.37 (notice the .37). walked almost 3km distance isn't adde/

Answer (score 3):

There are two important factors at play here - how and when Pokemon Go calculates distance.

PoGo isn't a fitness tracker - jogging on a treadmill won't do. You have to go outside, and then move slower than 10 miles/hour (18kph). Every few minutes (based on testing, this is around 4 minutes) the game queries the difference between your current position and your position 4 minutes ago, and credits you that distance in a straight line.

So to hatch your egg, walk or bike slowly in a straight line.

Comment: I've heard talk that simply shaking your device for a while will add distance to your eggs.

Comment: That is most likely a result of the counter "catching up" with distance you have walked, and people mistaking that as the effect of their shaking.

Comment: What about attaching your smartphone to a ceiling fan and letting it run. Did they fix that or was that just a hoax?

Comment: I can't imagine it ever did anything. I know that you occasionally get "free" meters from the GPS wandering around due to poor accuracy at the same time as the distance is captured.